# NetworkManagementSocketTagger: tagSocket(73) gettings spammed in logs

Tags: android, android-networking

I'm getting many, many entries in my Android app logging (I've replaced application id with xxx.xxx.xxx):

```
2021-09-14 09:40:11.131 21345-22853/xxx.xxx.xxx D/NetworkManagementSocketTagger: tagSocket(73) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
```

Apparently I'm not even seeing all of them as I also see:

```
2021-09-14 09:45:54.887 21345-22853/xxx.xxx.xxx I/chatty: uid=10302(xxx.xxx.xxx) RxCachedThreadS identical 22 lines
```

- I've checked out earlier versions of my code where I'm sure I didn't see it, and I still see the same logging. I'm guessing it's a recent SDK/API change in Android.
- I have done a bunch of Googling, but not found anything similar.
- The logging comes from com.android.server.NetworkManagementSocketTagger. I've looked at the source, but it's above my skill level to figure out what's going on in that code.
- I've looked at the change history of com.android.server.NetworkManagementSocketTagger but see no recent changes.

I'm not even sure what socket tagging is for. Can anyone help me out?